# Does $ABC=D\implies \det(ABC)=\det(D )$?

Tags: linear-algebra

$${\color{brown}{\text{Question I am trying to solve:}}}$$

Let $A,B$ and $X$ be 7 x 7 matrices such that $\det A=1$, $\det B=3$ and

$$A^{-1}XB^{t}=-I_7$$

where $I_7$ is the 7 x 7 identity matrix. Calculate $\det X$.

$$\color{brown}{------------------------------------}$$

**The way I thought to solve this is if the following is true:**

$$A^{-1}XB^{t}=-I_7 \implies \det(A^{-1}XB^{t})=\det(-I_7 )$$

---

$$\text{Then I could solve this by: }$$

$$\det (A^{-1}XB^{t})=\det(-I_7)$$

> $$\text{Note (since A, X, B are of the same size):}$$$$\bbox[8pt, border: 1pt solid green]{\det(A^{-1}XB^{t})=\det(A^{-1})\det(X)\det(B^t)}$$
>
> $$\text{Note:}$$
> $$\det(B^t)=\det (B)$$

$$\det(A^{-1})\det(X)\det(B^t)=\det(-I_7)$$

$$\frac{1}{1} \det(X) \cdot 3 = -1 \implies \bbox[8pt,border: 2pt #06f solid]{\det X=-\frac{1}{3}}$$

---

**So is it correct to do this :**

$$A^{-1}XB^{t}=-I_7 \implies \det(A^{-1}XB^{t})=\det(-I_7 )$$

$$\color{gold}{\Large{?}}$$

Comment: Yes. If two matrices are the same, they have the same determinant.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you :)

Comment: You might be looking for det(AB) = det(A)det(B) which is true in general.

Comment: @muaddib No , I already know this :) My question was if $AB=C$ can I take the determinant both sides to solve for an unknown determinant :)

Comment: Color me purple.

Comment: @muaddib haha??

Answer (score 4):

I might be missing something here, but as far as I know:

$a = a' \Rightarrow f(a) = f(a')$

for all sets $A,B$; $a,a'\in A$ and functions $f : A\to B$.